# VB6 - determine source of error

Tags: error-handling, vb6

I have searched both the internet and VB6 "help" without being able to find anything I can get to work. I'd like to know the line in my code that causes an error.

Can someone please show me the code that would report the line in my code that causes an error?

Comment: Not sure if you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12687105/11683) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1050570/11683) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3911973/11683).

Comment: Be more explicit on what you want to "see" as a result.

Comment: "that",  GSerg,  is what I'm interested in but I was reluctant to install MZTools (third party stuff can be risky) but that seems like the best option.

Comment: I installed then added MZTools3 in references but it doesn't show up either as context or toolbar or drop down. Note that I am running VB6 within SolidWorks and Excel with no luck.

Comment: No, you are using VBA, not VB6.

Comment: Bob77, you are correct. It seems to work as advertised now. Thanks to all for your help and patience.